# Error: Could not do a physical-order read to fetch next row

Tags: informix, locks

We're facing an issue

**Error logged in application server log:**

> "Error: Could not do a physical-order read to fetch next row"

We are using IBM informix 12.10 database.
I've checked for the locks using `onstat -k`, it shows the intent exclusive lock. While we are doing an insert operation we are facing this issue.
I have found the table what is making locking, i.e  `LO_hdr_partn`
I have checked online and find some solution like:

```
oncheck -ce.
```

We observed an error like:

> Validating extents for Space 'sbspace1' ...
>   ERROR: Could not obtain lock for Partnum 0xb00005

For resolution I've run the below commands:

```
run onspaces -cl <sbspace_name> and run the oncheck -ce.
```

But we're getting stuck again and again. Enable to insert the transaction. 
Any resolution for this?